# Java: Calling values from another class

Tags: java, arrays, eclipse, class

Ok so i have to make an appointment class with attributes private Date date and private Time time that refer to the already made classes with same name (Date, Time).. but the thing is.. My Date class has attributes day,month,year and Time has hour,minutes and I have already set their values.. How do I use private Date date in appointment class and get the values of the attributes of both the classes.. I am sorry if the question is a bit confusing or something.. I have been trying to figure this out but i dont even know what doing this is even called.. Is it called declaring another class in a new class or what? Please help. Thanks

Comment: please post some code. sounds like you need to read up on "pass by reference in java"

Comment: Why would you create your own Date and Time classes when Java API already has those?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand correctly, your classes look something like this:

```
  class Appointment {
    private Date date;
    private Time time;
    }

class Date {
private String day;
private String month;
private int year;
}

class Time {
private int hour;
private int minutes;
}
```

And you already have an instance on time and date each with their values set, now you want to set those values of date and time in appointment class?

if yes, you can either use Setters or a constructor.

if you use a setter your Appointment class would look something like this:

```
 class Appointment {
    private Date date;
    private Time time;

    public void setDate(Date date){
        this.date = date;
    }
    public void setTime(Time time) {
        this.time = time;
    }
}
```

Then you would use the above like:

```
public static void main(String[] args){
  Date yourDate = new Date("Monday",2,1993); //the date object which you already have
  Time yourTime = new Time(5,6); // the time object that you already have

  Appointment yourAppointment = new Appointment(); //creating an empty Appointment object
  yourAppointment.setDate(yourDate); //setting your created date in appointment
  yourAppointment.setTime(yourTime); //setting your created time in appointment
}
```

Or you could use a constructor instead of a setter in appointment class.
Now Appointment class would look like:

```
 class Appointment {
        private Date date;
        private Time time;

       private Appointment(Date date, Time time){
           this.date = date;
           this.time = time;
       }
    }
```

then you would set the date and time values like this:

```
    public static void main(String[] args){
      Date yourDate = new Date("Monday",2,1993); //the date object which you already have
  Time yourTime = new Time(5,6); // the time object that you already have

  Appointment yourAppointment = new Appointment(yourDate,yourTime); 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't know what you really wants to do, post some code.

Anyways, it sounds like you need to instance Date class and Time class on main class to work with it.

```
Date d=new Date();
Time t=new Time();
```

That would be on comment but I don't have enough rep yet. Sorry.

Answer (score 0):

If you have private attrubute ou your class, you need to have a "getter" mehod for access on other class. Please find below example of getter and setter:

```
private String myField; //"private" means access to this is restricted

    public String getMyField()
{
     //in order to have access
    return this.myField;
}
public void setMyField(String value)
{
     //in order to set value
     this.myField = value;
}
```